# How to get application process id that send SMS in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry

I'm looking for the way to get process id of the application which send SMS. I can get the content of sending message with OutboundMessageListener but I don't know how to get the process id.
Here is my try:

```
 MessageConnection _mc = (MessageConnection) Connector.open("sms://:0");
 _mc.setMessageListener(new OutboundSMSListener());

 private static final class OutboundSMSListener implements OutboundMessageListener
 {
    public void notifyIncomingMessage(MessageConnection messageconnection)
    {

      System.out.println("Incoming message received ");
    }

    public void notifyOutgoingMessage(Message message)
    {

      System.out.println("------------------------\n\n\n\n\n");
      System.out.println("Message send: " + message);
    }
 }
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Is the app sending SMS a native app of the BlackBerry device, and does it reside in the foreground?

For getting a foreground application's process id you can use the following code:

```
private int getForegroungProcessID() {
        return ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().getForegroundProcessId();
    }

private String getAppNameByProcessId(int id) {
        String result = null;

        ApplicationManager appManager = ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager();
        ApplicationDescriptor appDes[] = appManager.getVisibleApplications();

        for (int i = 0; i < appDes.length; i++) {
            if (appManager.getProcessId(appDes[i]) == id) {
                result = appDes[i].getModuleName();
                   //// here check the app name...is it a messaging app ///
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: It isn't just native app, it can be any app (maybe from third-party) that want to send sms in foreground. I want to catch the process id of it.